# NodeUnit enable harmony features

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeunit

I'm new to nodejs, and am not sure how I can enable harmony features in nodeunit?

I know I can enable them in `node` by using the `--harmony` flag, but `nodeunit` does not have this flag. I'm looking specifically to make `let` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not work for all cases, but we can add the --harmony flag in the nodeunit startup script:

batch:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --harmony "%~dp0\..\nodeunit\bin\nodeunit" %*
) ELSE (
  node --harmony "%~dp0\..\nodeunit\bin\nodeunit" %*
)
```

sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node" --harmony "$basedir/../nodeunit/bin/nodeunit" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node --harmony "$basedir/../nodeunit/bin/nodeunit" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, if you have nodeunit installed globally (`npm install -g nodeunit`), this works just fine:

```
node --harmony `which nodeunit` /path/to/tests
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac with the default install locations, a quick one liner:

```
node --harmony /usr/local/bin/nodeunit /path/to/your/testFile.js
```